# EC2 resourcetag with colon in aws

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to limit EC2 actions on any instance created by an autoscaling group. The group automaticaly create tag with key "aws:autoscaling:groupName" and value "my_as_group". So normaly i would set my policy like that :

```
    {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeInstances", 
            "ec2:DescribeImages",
            "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs", 
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:RunInstances", 
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances", 
            "ec2:StartInstances"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/*", // Yes, in reality I put my real id...
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "ec2:ResourceTag/aws:autoscaling:groupName": "my_as_group"
    }
  }
}
```

But in the IAM interface on aws.amazon.com, it displays the error :

> We encountered the follow errors while processing your request:
>
> Actions/Condition can contain only one colon.

After some tests, I think it don't want colon in the tag key... But the tag key is automatically created by amazon.

Any idea of how I can restrict these actions to instances created by the as group?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since tags beginning with "aws:" are restricted to AWS internal use (as mentioned both [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-CreateTags.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html)), it would have made more sense if the error stated that you couldn't do what you intended to do based on "aws:" in the tag.

However, since that's not the case and the error is more general, this seems to represent an inconsistency with documented behavior.  Doing what you're trying to do seems reasonable, based on the following statements, which are from the pages I linked to  in the previous paragraph:

> Constraints: Tag keys are case-sensitive and accept a maximum of 127 Unicode characters. May not begin with aws:
>
> Maximum key length—127 Unicode characters
>
> Tags don't have any semantic meaning to Amazon EC2 and are interpreted strictly as a string of characters

Well, something among those statements is inaccurate or incomplete if a `:` is not valid in an `ec2:resourcetag` in policy documents.

Of course, the next sentence from the docs seems also incorrect in light of the auto-generated tags that autoscaling adds:

> Also, tags are not automatically assigned to your resources.

Oops, except that it seems like in this case they are, and the documentation should say that, or should be more explicit that "aws:" tags may be, but not others.

It would be good if the documentation were accurate and complete, so I would suggest posting about your problem in the AWS forums and seeing if you get any attention from AWS personnel (assuming you don't have a paid support contract, in which case, I assume you would have used that).

On the other hand, I suppose we can't complain too much if the aws:* tags are outside the sphere of what we can access, since they apparently "[do not count against your limit of 10 tags per instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASTagging.html)."

## Possible Workaround

Perhaps you'll have luck posting on the forum, but if so, you might still find that these tags are inaccessible by design or by coincidence with a limitation in policy statements, and if that's the case, then it seems like this might be the workaround:

You could define a custom tag that serves to indicate that the instance is part of the auto-scaling group and then configure the autoscaling group to apply the tag to the instances for you.

> You can now add up to 10 tags to any of your Auto Scaling Groups. You can also, if you'd like, propagate the tags to the EC2 instances launched from your groups.
>
> <sup>— http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/01/new-tagging-features-for-auto-scaling-groups.html</sup>

That sounds promising.

> Optionally, you can propagate Auto Scaling group tags to the Amazon EC2 instances launched by Auto Scaling. The Auto Scaling group tags that you propagate to Amazon EC2 instances can be used like any other Amazon EC2 instance tag[...]
>
> When you use the PropagateAtLaunch flag with the as-create-or-update-tags command, the tag you create will be applied to new Amazon EC2 instances launched by the Auto Scaling group. Likewise, when you modify a tag, the updated version will be applied to new instances launched by the Auto Scaling group after the change. Tags created or modified with the as-create-or-update-tags command will not apply to instances that are already running at the time you used the command.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASTagging.html</sup>

This takes care of the instance, so long as you do not have any concern that your custom tag might be maliciously-applied to another instance as a way for the affected credentials to gain inappropriate control over another resource (though that implies that the malicious party already has access to the resource, so may not be a problem).

This won't help you with volumes connected to the EC2 instances, but it doesn't appear that autoscaling tags those anyway, so maybe this will do what you need.

A final thought, however, is that I'm not sure some of the actions you're wanting to permit could be tied to a tag on an instance... `DescribeImages`,
`ec2:DescribeKeyPairs`,
`ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups`,
`ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones`,
and `ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones` aren't, from what I can tell, going to be related to an "instance" resource.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you. For the last remark, yes I can do otherwise but since amazon automatically give me a tag, I thought it was a good idea to use it :)